# Change default error message for upload files on struts 2

Tags: java, file-upload, configuration, struts2, multipart

I there,

I have a multipart form that upload file and in `struts.xml` I was able to change the max size:

```xml
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10485760"/>
```

but I can't change the default error message when the request is bigger than allowed.

I've tried add `struts.messages.error.file.too.large=Too Large!` but I am always getting the same message:

> the request was rejected because its size (31720350) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)

Comment: That is the limit for the overall request, not for the single file size: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16934584/1654265

Comment: ok, but that doesn't answer my question.. how can I change the default message? And I tried use a interceptor but with a interceptor the action was skipping the validator.. So what you would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is coming from commons-fileupload framework which is default implementation of file uploading feature of the Struts2 framework. Struts2 also uses [`JakartaMultipartRequest` class](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/multipart/JakartaMultiPartRequest.html) to parse request. Even if you can change this class via configuration, you shouldn't do that. At the first look it seems to handle all exceptions thrown by underlying framework. For example you can change the value of the key

```
struts.messages.upload.error.SizeLimitExceededException=your message
```