# Large size image's base64 (as FormData param) not sent via AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, google-chrome

I am having an issue, when i send a large size image in base64 (around 20 MB) as a FormData param the AJAX POST request does not work. If it is less than 10 MB, the request FormData params work correctly. Why is it behaving like this?

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(“base64Image”, “<LARGE SIZE BASE64 STRING>”);
$.ajax({
   url : "/api/extensions",// no i18n
   method : "POST",//no i18n
   processData : false,
   contentType : false,
   data : formData
   ...
});
```

Comment: Define "not going".

Comment: sounds like some server setting is stopping it, if it consistantly fail > 10mb, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249587/is-it-any-limit-for-post-data-size-in-ajax

Comment: Base64 request param not sent in the browser Network tab if it is around 20 MB.

Comment: @juju It is a client side issue right? The browser is not even sending it in the request.

Comment: ah I didn't know there was a restiction client side, apart from performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a server issue. Not sure what server you're using but in Payara I think they configure the max allowed upload size like this;

`max-post-size-bytes`, can be configured also in admin console, setting it to -1 will remove size limits and accept any request

`max-form-post-size-bytes`
this cannot be configured in Admin console, only via asadmin command
this is only being applied to requests with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, therefore it is ignored for most form file uploads"

from [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/666)

**EDIT**: from other questions I've seen on the internet about this exact issue, there have been dodgy server config/php_ini files that haven't been parsed properly, multiple settings files that you might have to configure, but for struts, could you try and implement the example in [this](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload.html#file-size-limits) walk through? Also, are you sure your config has 100000000 bytes and not 10000000?

Comment: I am using Java Struts 2

Comment: seems like you answer could be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821334/limit-struts2-file-upload-max-size-without-uploading-the-whole-file#answer-4823524

Comment: I edited the question with my code. Does it work if I try with application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data request?

Comment: Nah multi part should be fine, as far as I know, Ajax doesn't have a limit and neither does formats as I've used them with large files. So it has to be something else

Comment: Have you seen this post? Without seeing server config it's hard to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225881/not-able-to-upload-large-files